# Доказательство терминируемости рекурсивной функции

Tags: рекурсия

Всем привет. Готовлюсь к экзамену. Есть такой топик: доказать, что терминирует рекурсивная функция.

Доказательство основано на том, что нужно найти некую уменьшающуюся/снижающуюся функцию h и при помощи нее провести доказательство.

Прошу помощи или литературы, где толково описано с примерами как делаются такие доказательства.

Upadte Спасибо за требование разъяснить - для меня это показатель интерес коллег к вопросу. Итак, поясняю:

Вопрос касается доказательства корректности работы программы.
Для того, чтобы доказать корректность работы программы необходимо:
пусть f функция, которая выполняет роль спецификации к программе (для всех х принадлежащих некому множеству (определенному в спецификации) D). Пусть g функция, которая характеризует функцию, реализованную в программе.

Существует 2 вида доказательства корректности:

1. Частичная корректность работы программы: частичная корректность заключается в следующем: если предположить, что программа терминирует, то g(x)=f(x)
2. Полная (тотальная) корректность гарантирует и соответствие реализации спецификации (g(x)=f(x)) и терминирование программы.

Один из способов доказательства тотальной корректности для рекурсивных алгоритмов состоит в поиске "спадающей" функции (ее еще называют терминирующая функция).
Терминирующая функция выбирается таким образом, чтобы ее значения для всех х ограничивали функцию f(x), т.е. являлась верхней и нижней ее границей. Далее при помощи этой функции и математической индукции показывают, что дерево рекурсивных вызовов конечно.

Т.е. принцип понятен, но для того, чтобы самостоятельно проводить такие доказательства и другим объяснять хотелось бы понимать следующее:

1. Механику доказательства: как выбирать спадающую функцию (желательно на примерах), как с ее помощью показать конечность рекурсивных вызовов программы...
2. Есть ли другие практики доказательств ТОТАЛЬНОЙ корректности
3. Есть ли литература с примерами

Comment: всем привет. Так как у нас с вопросом затруднения, а понимать хочется - задал вопрос профессору Сергею Михайловичу Абрамову. И он, спасибо ему огромное, ответил следующее: "Более общий подход такой:

Пусть для любого x вычисление f(x) приводить к цепочке редукций:

f(x) -> e1 -> e2 -> e3 -> ...

Придумаем некое отображение g(eK) -> yK, где yK числа или
алгебраические структуры из класса Ord (для них есть <, >, <=, >=, ==,
/=)

Comment: продолжение ответа профессора: "Если мы покажем, что для любого x цепочка yK монотонно убывает и при
этом бесконечно она убывать не может (хорошо фундирована снизу), то
цепочка редукций не может быть бесконечной.  Функциая f терминируема.

Так доказывается, чтои любая примитивно-рекурсивная функция
терминируется.  Дело в том, что у нее есть один из аргументов, который
монотонно убывает и положителен.  Ясно, как устроено g(eK) -> yK: надо
рассматривать этот аргумент".